# Python: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python, authentication

I was trying to load a web page, but I ran into this problem. I do have the username and password, but I don't know how to use them in python code. I looked up on python tutorial, and this is what I wrote:

```
import urllib2

password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
top_level_url = "www.something.com:80"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
opener.open('http://www.something.com/h/h.html')
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen()
page = response.read()
print page
```

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 22):

Here is working code

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.abc.com/index.html'
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

p.add_password(None, url, username, password)

handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you can use the `requests` module which would make it easier for you.

```
import requests
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
url = 'http://www.example.com/index.html'
r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))  
page = r.content
print page
```

Comment: Could be because of my python version, but just to let others know: I had to remove the parentheses on r.content() to get this to work (page = r.content).